# StackLayout and ListView Sizing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a listview in a stacklayout. If the listview is shorter than the height of the stacklayout's container, stacklayout's height should wrap its content. If it is longer, stacklayout will have its max. height and the listview will scroll.

In short, I want to assign a non-static max height to the stacklayout but the following gives it its max. height even though the list is short:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="White">
    <Label Text="Hello" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding options}" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can wrap your StackLayout within AbsoluteLayout..and do not forget to set 'Orientation' property.  Hope this helps